# My code never reaches the Monitor.Pulse line

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have this code

```
    private object volatile objLock = new object();



   void Foo()
    {
      // doing something
      lock(objLock)
      {
        Monitor.Wait(objLock);
      }
      // finish up
    }

    void Bar()
    {
      lock(objLock)
      {
         Monitor.Pulse(objLock);
      }
    }
```

The both these functions are triggered as an event handler from an external device and will be i **different threads**!

My problem is that when Bar() is called it stops on the lock(objLock) line. Which to me indicates that objLock already is locked...

If I call Foo() from the main application (via a button) then everything works perfectly!

What have I done wrong?

I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: Put a breakpoint on **all** `lock(objLock)` lines. Debug the app. Which `lock` gets hit first?

Comment: This is hard to diagnose without a debugger in the first place. And it is impossible to diagnose without the code that is executed on the threads.

Comment: Foo locks the object so you never get to Pulse.  Run Bar before FOO and you should get to Pulse.

Comment: The `important` remarks under https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2 may be worth a read. But putting that to one side, this feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Can you talk us through the underlying reason why you want this code? What is it trying to achieve?

Answer (score -2):

> The both these functions are triggered as an event handler from an external device and will be i different threads!

I think they will be called on the same thread. A bit of a guess but that is the only condition under which they can block each other.

When `Wait()` blocks further event processing.

Comment: But how should they be running on the same thread? If `Foo` waits and blocks its thread,`Bar` cannot be executed on that very thread.

Comment: @RenéVogt - that is the speculation part. But Wait() is incompatible with most event driven systems.

Comment: there is no speculation, it's simply technically impossible. If a thread stands in `Monitor.Wait()` in `Foo()`, it cannot stand at the `lock` in `Bar` at the same time.

Comment: @RenéVogt - You only have to stand at the Wait(). When that blocks the events then there never will be a Pulse. Except when "I call Foo() from the main application (via a button)"

Comment: The event loop is blocking, not the Monitor.

Comment: OP is stating that "it stops on the lock(objLock) line"....`Bar` **is called**. And since `Foo` still waits, it's obviously called on a different thread.

Comment: @RenéVogt - that is the part I chose not to believe. This is heavily pseudo code.